# PHP: Slow query execution

Tags: php, performance

I have this login sistem:

```
    require_once "conexion.php";


    class login extends conexion {



    public function log_user($user,$pass)
        {
        $conexion = mysql_conexion();
            $login = "SELECT user_name,user_pass,id FROM menssager_user WHERE user_name='$user' AND user_pass='$pass'";
                $e = $conexion->prepare($login);
                    $e->execute();

                $re = $e->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if($user == $re["user_name"] && $pass == $re["user_pass"])
                    {

                    $this->is_online($re["id"]);
                    return $re["id"];
                    }

        $conexion = null;

        }   }
```

And when i execute that code, it takes 1.3 seconds to find out if that user exists and I have just 2 username in the DB.
Can someone tell me why so slow?
Note: yesterday i upgrade to 5.4.7 and re-write the code again(for new features of that version).

Update:

And the database conexion:

```
class conexion{

        public function mysql_conexion(){

            $conexion_path = "mysql:dbname=menssager;host:127.0.0.1";
                $root = "root";
                $pass = "";

                try{

                    $conectar = new PDO($conexion_path,$root,$pass);
                    $conectar->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
                    $conectar->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                }catch(PDOException $error)
                {
                    echo $conectar = $error->getMessage();
                }
                return $conectar;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on user_name and user_pass fields? Though with only two rows I am still a little baffled at how the query would take that long unless you have lots of other fields in that table with a large amount of data and/or a terrible hardware setup. Also why bother returning the user_name and user_pass values back and re-verifying them.  It's not like that are changing between the time you create the prepared statement and make the comparison. Finally, if you are going to use prepared statements, you should actually use bound parameters to pass in your data.

Comment: its no only in the login sistem. Also i have a simple query that i use to know if the user is online or not and it takes 1.2 seconds as well. Since i started using extends php, my queries are being executing really slow.

Comment: what is `extends php`?

Comment: It only takes 0.0004s to execute and show the results if I query directly in the database.

Comment: Can you check by running the same query using a standard database client from the same machine where you are running this code? That would be able to tell you whether the problem is within your code or outside it.

Comment: @MikeBrant its inheritance the attributes of another class.

Comment: @NGAlgo I just did, and it takes 0.0004s.

Comment: Is the database located on the same machine? Also, you should really use bound variables instead of injecting your variables directly in the query. And you only need to check if a row is found afterwards.

Comment: @EinerSantanaR That is very telling, it is likely your code in setting up your connections that is problematic. You can easily use `microtime()` to add timers in you application to see where the time is actually spent.

Comment: @EinerSantanaR OK I am extremely familiar with OOP concepts, I thought you where talking about some kind of "extends PHP" framework or something.  I have never heard someone talk about using inheritance and OOP in PHP as using "extends PHP" before.

Comment: @MikeBrant can u give a axample of "bound parameters"? Id like to know.

Comment: @Mike unfortunately I think everything would end up under execute() unless he can peel back the libraries and make distinction between establishing a connection and executing the query.

Comment: @Einer Are you trying to connect via an IP address or a DNS name. Perhaps name resolution is being problematic for you, can you switch to IP address and try? Or even try to use 127.0.0.1 since you are on the same machine anyway.

Comment: @MikeBrant so, what do you use insted of it?

Comment: @NGAlgo i am using 127.0.0.1 not localhost

Comment: I updated the post, you can see the conexion code now.

Comment: @NGAlgo There is a separate `mysql_conexion();` call which I am guessing performs the connection. You could also see time specifically around `prepare()` and `execute()`.

Comment: can you narrow it down by measuring time taken to execute 
     `$conectar = new PDO($conexion_path,$root,$pass);`
vs the time taken to execute
    `$e->execute();`

Comment: I have a feeling that establishing the initial connection is taking most time for you. when you tried it locally you would not have taken the initial connection time into account. If your application can pre-create the connection, and then simply measure time taken to execute the query (or multiple queries), you might find query execution is as fast as you expect when running this locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are still measuring the connection vs execution times, I am going to hazard a guess at the answer. I think your connection time is what is causing the delays. Look at this similar question asked earlier.
https://serverfault.com/questions/408550/connecting-to-mysql-from-php-is-extremely-slow

Turning off reverse DNS lookup might help you. 
Adding a link showing how you can turn it off:

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/01/10/howto-turn-off-mysql-reverse-dns-lookup-to-speed-up-response-times/

Comment: No, the same problem. OMG still in 1 second

Comment: So, after speding some large hours looking to fix that problem I came across with this post and what i just did was the first one http://faq.webyog.com//content/23/36/en/i-get-error-1130-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-or-access-denied-or-could-not-connect-.html I hope that help someone alse. Now it takes 21ms to execute :D

Comment: Its great that your problem is solved! However even though you have fixed your etc/hosts file for the entry of localhost, you may still run into issues when you are connecting from various external client machines who dont have any entry in the hosts file of the server. I would think you need a mysql config change to ensure it does not waste time looking up the client's name.